# css3 transitionend doesn't fire on firefox

Tags: javascript, css

Please look at the next [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw8fV/2/) and help me understand why in Firefox, the alerts aren't fired.

HTML

```
<div class="test1">TEST1</div>
```

CSS

```
.test1 {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: opacity 0.2s 0 ease-in;
    &.fade-in {
        opacity: 1
    }

}
```

JS

```
    $(".test1").ready(function(){
        $(".test1").one("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend MSTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd transitionEnd", function(event){
        alert("transition fired");
        if ( event.target == event.currentTarget ) {
            alert(event.target);
        }
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".test1").addClass("fade-in");
        },1000);
    });
```

Updated code and fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add -moz- at defor of animation property

```
-moz-transition: PROPERTY or CSS CLASS NAME .3s ease;
```

example: 
    -moz-transition: width .3s ease;

```
-moz-transition: fade-out .3s ease;
```

Comment: I did, in my program I use compass so I do @include transition which adds all browsers prefixes. On the JSFiddle I've added what you said, but still, it doesn't fire

Comment: there is some problem in code the fiddle not worked in chrome also

Comment: hey Alon, for the fade effect you need to write key frames to obtain the required animation effect

Comment: adding a class won't fire the event ?

Comment: yes because the process simply change the opacity level only if you add key frame means customize the increase rate of the opacity

Comment: Thanks, I've decided in the end to use jquery transit plugin